# How to publish typescript ReactJS component on npm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, components

I would like to make a new ReactJS component with Typescript and publish it on npm.
My idea is to have only a project folder with:

- `/dist` build for final distribution on npm
- `node_modules`
- `/public` where I will have my `index.js` to locally run my app for development purposes and one folder components where all files for my distributed component will be stored (only component folder will be published)
- and other files like `.gitignore`, `.npmignore`, `package.json` and so on..

Something like this:

[image: Folder tree]

I have seen many guides (and spent many hours) figuring out how to publish a ReactJS component like:

- [Create an NPM Package from a React Component](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esyS87NfBOw)
- [Create a React Component Library using TypeScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcThWngBv7U)
- [How To Make a React Component Library - Making A React Library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8d-CLmg3hw)
- [Publish A React Component On NPM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYm6BJ_QvDg)
- [`create-react-library`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library)

But most of them have such a complicated structure (like script files, babel files, webpacks ..) and generated files that I don't understand.

My idea was to use `react-script` to run and develop the app locally and then run `tsc` to compile my component to build. I thought that I don't need create-react-app/library, babel or webpack to publish a react component - if they are necessary, why do we need them? I just thought it should be possible to do it simply and lightly - like just to take tsx files compile them into js..

To me, it seems that the process of publishing a ReactJS component library with TS to npm is not that well documented. Can you please provide steps or some well and easy-to-understand guide on how to publish react component? Also with all the configurations (configuration files), since I think I messed it somewhere there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're confusing the source code and what gets published. If you're using something like TypeScript then your repo will likely *not* contain the package contents, you'll have raw source and configuration then the package will be generated at publish time; see e.g. my package https://github.com/textbook/fauxauth, where lib, which is what you get when you install it, is **not** in the repo.

Comment: would ask the same question :). any news on that?